# Bottom nav not alligning to bottom

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have succefully made a bottomNavigation but when I execute my code it appears to be at the top instead as at the bottom of the screen, do I need to do something else?

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavWithLabels(){
    BottomNavigation(content = {
        listItems.forEachIndexed { index, label ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                    icon = {
                                Icon(vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24))
                          
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: can you share us layout code?

Comment: Thats the layout code, is jetpack compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `BottomNavWithLabels()` with a `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(topBar = { },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavWithLabels()
        },
        bodyContent = {
    //bodyContent()
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabriele, could this be implemented as the default implementation of BottomNavView instead of ussing a scaffold, I think that is why is called BottomNavView hmm

Comment: @CoffeeBreak You can use the `BottomNavView` also without the `Scaffold`. Just put it in another container (`Box`, `Column`, `Row`...) with the preferred gravity.